# How to find documents that is equal or includes today in its date range?

Tags: mongodb

Given the date, how can I find and return only documents that are in the range or equal to the start or end date in Mongo DB?

```
"startDate" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
"endDate" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 

"startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-24T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
"endDate" : ISODate("2020-05-23T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
.........
```

Here it is the solution:

```
$and: [
        { "startDate": { $lte: new ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000") } }, 
        { "endDate": { $gte: new ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000") } }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ISODate(...)` (which is an alias for `new Date(...)`)

You can skip `$and`, if you like:

```
{ 
   "startDate": { $lte: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000") } ,
   "endDate": { $gte: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000") }
}
```

A more dynamic and easier way would be to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

```
{
   startDate: { $lte: moment().startOf('day').toDate() },
   endDate: { $gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query condition for the start date should specify the date `2020-01-01` and the hours as `00:00:00`. The end date should specify the date and the hours as `23:59:59`, so as to include all hours in the day.

For example, the following query will match all times of the day, assuming the date is `2020-01-01`. The query matches all the times within the day, i.e., from `00:00:00` hours to `23:59:59` hours. Note the `$gte` and the `$lte` are used with start and end date's respectively.

```
{ 
  startDate: { $gte: new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000") }, 
  endDate: { $lte: new Date("2020-01-01T23:59:59.000+0000") } 
}
```

The date can be specified as `ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")` *or* `new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")`.

In the query filter, the `$and` operator is optional. The query can be as follows:

```
db.collection.find( 
  { 
    startDate: { $gte: ISODate("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000+0000") }, 
    endDate: { $lte: ISODate("2020-04-04T23:59:59.000+0000") } 
  }
)
```